# how can spilit img src form this js html variable ( this is rss that i call it )

Tags: javascript, html, rss, rss-reader

```
var a = '<p><img loading="lazy" class="size-full wp-image-6491 aligncenter" src="https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance.jpg" alt="" width="1200" height="676" srcset="https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance.jpg 1200w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-300x169.jpg 300w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-1024x577.jpg 1024w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-768x433.jpg 768w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-1000x563.jpg 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px"></p>'
```

how can spilit img src form this js html variable ( this is rss that i call it )

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegExp::exec` with `g` flag and a backward assertion to search inside `srcset` attribute:

```js
var a = '<p><img loading="lazy" class="size-full wp-image-6491 aligncenter" src="https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance.jpg" alt="" width="1200" height="676" srcset="https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance.jpg 1200w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-300x169.jpg 300w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-1024x577.jpg 1024w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-768x433.jpg 768w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-1000x563.jpg 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px"></p>'

const regex = /(?<=srcset=".*)([^\s]+) (\d+)w/g;

const images = [];
let m;
while(m = regex.exec(a)){
  const [, src, width] = m;
  images.push({src, width});
}

console.log(images);
```

Comment: but this code doesnt work , please check it again

Comment: @hosseinghodrati please give your desired output otherwise your task isn't clearly described

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = '<p><img loading="lazy" class="size-full wp-image-6491 aligncenter" src="https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance.jpg" alt="" width="1200" height="676" srcset="https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance.jpg 1200w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-300x169.jpg 300w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-1024x577.jpg 1024w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-768x433.jpg 768w, https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance-1000x563.jpg 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px"></p>';

var src = a.match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1];

console.log(src); // https://rahaimport.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Export-clearance-clearance.jpg
```

First, we use the match() method to find the src attribute in the HTML variable.
The match() method returns an array of strings, where each string is a match for the specified regular expression.
In this case, the regular expression matches the src attribute, and the first string in the array is the image URL.